# Cucumber::Undefined error something to worry about?

Tags: cucumber, bdd

My cucumber feature file is as follows

```
Feature: Create and Manage Videos
    In order to record a video
    As a registered user
    I want to create and manage videos

    Scenario: sent videos list
        Given I have sent video titled "Happy Birthday" to "My Friend X"
        When I go to my outbox list of videos
        Then I should see "Happy Birthday" video 
        And I should see "My Friend X"
```

I run cucumber using the following command

```
cucumber features
```

I get the following output

```
Using the default profile... 
Feature: Create and Manage Videos
  In order to record a video
  As a registered user
  I want to create and manage videos

  Scenario: sent videos list                                         #       features/manage_video.feature:6
    Given I have sent video titled "Happy Birthday" to "My Friend X" # features/manage_video.feature:7
      Undefined step: "I have sent video titled "Happy Birthday" to "My Friend X"" (Cucumber::Undefined)
      features/manage_video.feature:7:in `Given I have sent video titled "Happy Birthday" to "My Friend X"'
    When I go to my outbox list of videos                            # features/manage_video.feature:8
      Undefined step: "I go to my outbox list of videos" (Cucumber::Undefined)
  features/manage_video.feature:8:in `When I go to my outbox list of videos'
Then I should see "Happy Birthday" video                         # features/manage_video.feature:9
      Undefined step: "I should see "Happy Birthday" video" (Cucumber::Undefined)
  features/manage_video.feature:9:in `Then I should see "Happy Birthday" video'
    And I should see "My Friend X"                                   # features/manage_video.feature:10
      Undefined step: "I should see "My Friend X"" (Cucumber::Undefined)
  features/manage_video.feature:10:in `And I should see "My Friend X"'

1 scenario (1 undefined)
4 steps (4 undefined)
0m1.877s
```

Below this I get a bunch of snippets which I will use in the steps_definition file.

My question is :: Are these Cucumber::Undefined errors something to worry about?

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are!  This indicates that none of your tests are actually being executed.  You don't say if you've actually written step definitions or not.  If you have, then Cucumber isn't finding these, if you aren't using the conventional folder structure then you'll need to tell Cucumber where these are located using

```
cucumber -r my_step_defs_location features
```

Replacing `my_step_defs_location` with the folder containing your step definitions.